# Find Static, instance and local variables in this python code

Tags: python, oop, instance, instance-variables

Here is the question of a python code asked on InfyTQ mock test.

```
class classOne:
  __var_one = 1001

  def __init__(self,var_two):
     self.__var_two = var_two
     self.__var_five = 5

  def method_one(self):
     var_four = 50
     self.__var_five = ClassOne.__var_one + self.__var_two + var_four
```

Now, I want to ask if the variable
`self.__var_five` of function `method_one` should be considered a new instance variable or not?
Because there is already a `self.__var_five` in `__init__` function.

Also,
I learned the concept of global,local,static and instance variable from given below code.
Is it correct?

```
#global, local, static, instance variable.
#global variable are defined at the top of program or defined using keyword:global

global global_var1 = 0
global_var2 = 1

def local_variable:
    #local variable are defined inside of a function.
    local_var1 = 2

class static_instance:
    #static/classs variable are defined inside of a class.
    static_var1 = 3

    def __init__(self):
        #all variables defined in the function of a class starting with self.
        self.instance_var1 = 4

    def static(self):
        self.instance_var2 = 5

        local_var2 = 6         #local variable as it is in a function.

    static_var2 = 6
```

Comment: The bold thing within the thing is actually self.__var_five. I don't know how to make it not bold.

Comment: Put inline code in backticks to prevent that.

Comment: "Static" isn't a useful description in Python. In C, you mark a function-local variable as static to indicate it should be allocated on the heap, rather than the stack, where its value persists even after the function returns. In Python, all attributes are associated with an object; there's little difference between a class attribute and an instance attribute, aside from what kind of object they are attached to. (Indeed, once you start talking about metaclasses, whether you think of an attribute as a class attribute or an instance attribute is just a matter of perspective....

Comment: Thanks @Barmar for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the same instance variable (called an *attribute* in Python). `method_one` is simply updating its value.

Most of your understandings in the second code block are correct. However, when a method does:

```
self.static_var1 = 4
```

it creates an instance attribute named `static_var1`. This is independent of the class attribute that was declared outside the methods, which is shared among all instances that don't reassign it. But since you do the assignment in the `__init__()` method, all instances get their own attribute. The only way to access the static value would be with `static_instance.static_var1`.